# How to set template reference dynamically inside function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a function below from which I am calling `setModelData`.

My query is I want to make template variable dynamic for both `getGlobalList` and `getNonGlobalList` function.

**For Example**

1)  if `getGlobalList` is running it will set **template: this.CustomTableItemTemplate**
 inside the `setModelData` function.

2)  if `getNonGlobalList` is running it will pass **template: this.NonGlobalCustomTableItemTemplate**
 inside the `setModelData` function.

Thanks for help

**Code**

```js
@ViewChild('CustomTableItemTemplate') CustomTableItemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('NonGlobalCustomTableItemTemplate') NonGlobalCustomTableItemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;


ngOnInit() {
  this.getGlobalList();
  this.getNonGlobalList();  
}

getGlobalList() {
  this.globalSchemamodel.data.length = 0;

  this.Service.getGlobalList(
    this.constructQueryParam(this.globalSchemamodel, 'global'))
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        const globalSchemas = response ? response.data : [];
        if (globalSchemas.records) {
          this.setModelData(globalSchemas, this.globalSchemamodel);
        }     
      });
} 

getNonGlobalList() {
  this.nonGlobalSchemamodel.data.length = 0;

  this.Service.getList(
    this.constructQueryParam(this.nonGlobalSchemamodel, 'nonglobal'))
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        const nonglobalschemaslist = response ? response.data : [];
        if (nonglobalschemaslist.records) {
          this.setModelData(nonglobalschemaslist, this.nonGlobalSchemamodel);
        }     
      });

} 

setModelData(globalSchemas, globalSchemamodel) {
  for (const schema of globalSchemas.records) {
    const tableModel = [
     new TableItem({ data: schema.schema_id }),
       this.isAdminRole ? new TableItem({
       data:[{ 'schemaId': schema.schema_id }],
       **template: this.CustomTableItemTemplate**
     }) : null
    ];
    globalSchemamodel.data.push(tableModel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setModelData` function needs another `template` param that's for sure.

Additionally you can extract similar code from `getNonGlobalList` and `getGlobalList`

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getList(
    this.globalSchemamodel,
    this.Service.getGlobalList,
    'global',
    this.CustomTableItemTemplate
  );
  this.getList(
    this.nonGlobalSchemamodel,
    this.Service.getList',
    'nonglobal',
    this.NonGlobalCustomTableItemTemplate
  );  
}

getList(model: any, functionToCall: any, paramName: string, template: TemplateRef<any>) {

  model.data.length = 0;

  functionToCall(
    this.constructQueryParam(model, paramName))
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        const schemas = response ? response.data : [];
        if (schemas.records) {
          this.setModelData(schemas.records, model);
        }     
      });
} 

setModelData(schemas: any[], schemaModel: any, template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  for (const { schema_id } of schemas) {
    const tableModel = [
      new TableItem({ 
        data: schema_id
      }),
      this.isAdminRole ? new TableItem({
      data: [
        {
          'schemaId': schema_id
        }
       ],
       template
     }) : null
    ];
    schemaModel.data.push(tableModel);
  }
}
```